# Can I see in the Weblogic Administration Console the logs of a logger that I created?

Tags: logging, log4j, weblogic

I mean if I use a **Java logger** in my application..

```
private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("InfoLogging");
LOGGER.info("Logging an INFO-level message");
```

Is there a way to access to the logs that this logger creates from the **Weblogic Administration Console**.

I know you can access to the **Weblogic** logs in `Domain Structure -> Diagnostics -> Log Files`. But I cannot see there my `InfoLogging` logger.

Comment: Are you using log4j? What does your log4j.properties file look like and what logging level. Also check the logging tab for your managed server in the weblogic console and verify the logging level is set to at least INFO.

Comment: Yes, I use log4j, and I have 2 handlers for my logger, one of them puts the output on the console and the other one puts it into a file that I specified. So my question would be, if Could I check the content of this file I mentioned before in the Weblogic Console?

Answer (score 0):

You can view server logs through the console by doing the following:

```
Click Diagnostics link on left hand side

Click Log Files link

Check the radio button for the log you are interested and click the View button
```

You will probably want to customize the table for that log to show a larger time interval and more message per page.